# How to replace a term with some property of the term?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I apologize if this example is contrived, I am attempting to prove a similar Lemma with a more complex function than `list_even`. I wish to prove some property about a translation of a list.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.
Import ListNotations.

Definition list_even (c : list nat) := map Nat.even c.

Lemma list_even_split : forall (c : list nat),
  c = nil \/
    exists c1 c2 b,
      c = c1 ++ c2
      /\ list_even c1 = b :: nil
      /\ list_even c = b :: list_even c2.
```

The proof I came up with is as follows.

```
Proof.
  intros c.
  induction c.
  - left. reflexivity.
  - right.
    exists [a].
    exists c.
    (* I am stuck here. *)
    assert (e := Nat.even a).
```

If I were to prove this by hand, my argument goes as follows.

Let `c = [a] :: c2`, so `c1 = [a]`. By `Nat.Even_or_Odd`, `a` is even or it is odd. If `a` is even, then `b = true` and so

```
  c = [a] ++ c2 /\
  list_even [a] = [true] /\
  list_even c = true :: list_even c2
```

If `a` is odd, then `b = false` and so

```
  c = [a] ++ c2 /\
  list_even [a] = [false] /\
  list_even c = false :: list_even c2
```

which hold by simplification and reflexivity.

However, I do not know how to translate the proof state of

```
a : nat
  c : list nat
  IHc : c = [] \/
        (exists (c1 c2 : list nat) (b : bool),
           c = c1 ++ c2 /\
           list_even c1 = [b] /\ list_even c = b :: list_even c2)
  ============================
  exists b : bool,
    a :: c = [a] ++ c /\
    list_even [a] = [b] /\ list_even (a :: c) = b :: list_even c
```

into one which proceeds with the evenness of `a`.

I also do not believe I need induction for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even-ness isn't actually important to this goal, as it is just a fact about mapping. Either `c` is the empty list, or `c` is of the form `c = x :: xs = [x] ++ xs` so `map Nat.even c = Nat.even x ++ map Nat.even xs`. As such, you could have a proof like

```
Lemma list_even_split : forall (c : list nat),
  c = nil \/
    exists c1 c2 b,
      c = c1 ++ c2
      /\ list_even c1 = b :: nil
      /\ list_even c = b :: list_even c2.
Proof.
  intros c. 
   destruct c as [|x xs]; [left; auto 
                    |right; exists (x::nil); do 2 eexists; repeat split; eauto].
Qed.
```

However, in other cases where one needs evenness of a variable you can record it via

```
destruct (Nat.even x) eqn : NAT_IS_EVEN
```

Comment: The `destruct` clause was my original question. This proof does work but there's a lot going on within the second set of brackets. What's happening there is: the left side of `|` is for the first case being destructed.

Why exactly the `repeat split; eauto` works is not clear to me since if you convert `repeat split; eauto` into `split. eauto. split. eauto.` etc, the proof does not complete.